# What properties must a language have to support recursion?

Tags: recursion, programming-languages

I was studying about recursion and I came across this question:

> FORTRAN implementations do not permit recursion because
>
> a. they use static allocation for variables
>
> b. they use dynamic allocation for variables
>
> c. stacks are not available on all machines
>
> d. it is not possible to implement recursion on all machines.

I found out that the answer was (a)

But I want to know all the features that a programming language should have to support the recursion.

Answer (score 6):

In order to support general recursion, a language needs a way to allocate different activation records for different invocations of the same function.  That way, local variables allocated in one recursive call can coexist with local variables allocated in a different call.

There are very few languages that by design can't support recursion; these are usually languages with no explicit notions of functions (take brainf*ck as an example).  Most languages these days have runtime environments that include either an explicit function stack or some other way to allocate stack frames.  As a result, most modern languages support recursion.  Other than FORTRAN and esoteric languages, I'm not aware of any languages that don't support it.

Hope this helps!